# Weave two dictionaries into one

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {'a': 1,
         'b': 2,
         'c': 3,
         'd': 4,
         'x': 5}
```

and

```
dict2 = {'a': 'start',
         'b': 'start',
         'c': 'end',
         'd': 'end'}
```

I am trying to create a new dictionary that maps the values `start` and `end` as keys to a dictionary that would contain the info of `dict1`, while keeping those that are not present in `dict2` as keys, e.g.:

```
dict3 = {'start': {'a': 1, 'b': 2},
         'end': {'c': 3, 'd': 4},
         'x': {'x': 5}
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`dict.setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) to create the nested dictionaries in `dict3` if not yet there, and [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to determine the key in the top-level output dictionary:

```
dict3 = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    nested = dict3.setdefault(dict2.get(k, k), {})
    nested[k] = v
```

So `dict2.get(k, k)` will produce the value from `dict2` for a given key from `dict1`, using the key itself as a default. So for the `'x'` key, that'll produce `'x'` as there is no mapping in `dict2` for that key.

Demo:

```
>>> dict3 = {}
>>> for k, v in dict1.items():
...     nested = dict3.setdefault(dict2.get(k, k), {})
...     nested[k] = v
...
>>> dict3
{'start': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'end': {'c': 3, 'd': 4}, 'x': {'x': 5}}
```

Comment: Readability note: if you do this, *please* leave a comment as to what this is doing. This is using setdefault in a novel way and as such would be quite cryptic without some sort of explanation.

Comment: @TemporalWolf this is using `dict.setdefault()` *as designed*. I'm not sure what is novel about how it used here.

Comment: It may be obvious how this works for you, but it was not clear to me and I would consider this a spot where [block or inline comments](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html?showone=Comments#Comments) applies: "Complicated operations get a few lines of comments before the operations commence. Non-obvious ones get comments at the end of the line."

Comment: @TemporalWolf: What I meant was that using `dict.setdefault()` to fetch a value for a key, setting a default value if missing before doing so, is a straightforward uses of the method, but you called it novel. Is it perhaps that I use `dict.setdefault()` *at all* that is new to you? It's been part of the standard library `dict` object since Python 2.0 at least (so 2001).

Comment: My comment was poorly worded: I still think this, as an invert & merge, deserves a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I actually figured it out while abstracting the example and typing up my question here (should have maybe done this earlier...). Anyways: Yay!

So here is my solution, in case it may help someone. If someone knows a swifter or more elegant way to do it, I would be glad to learn!

```
dict3 = dict()

for k, v in dict1.items():
    # if the key of dict1 exists also in dict2
    if k in dict2.keys():
        # get its value (the keys-to-be for the new dict3)
        new_key = dict2[k]
        # if the new key is already in the new dict
        if new_key in dict3.keys():
            # appends new dict entry to dict3
            dict3[new_key].update({k: v})
        # otherwise create a new entry
        else:
            dict3[new_key] = {k: v}
    # if there is no corresponding mapping present
    else:
        # treat the original key as the new key and add to dict3
        no_map = k
        dict3[no_map] = {k: v}
```